# How to add Array Data to Array in AlpineJS

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I try to make a form with Laravel and AlpineJS, which accepts multiple Languages. I now have multiple checkboxes for each language (not the native language). I now want to add an input for each language, which is selected. When i now check a checkbox, the given "value"-data is not properly added to the "languages"-array.

Console.log gives the following result:

`0 : Proxy {id: 0, label: 'de'} 1 : "{'id' : 1, 'label' : 'en'}" 2 : "{'id' : 2, 'label' : 'fr'}"`

Code:

```
<div x-data="{ languages: [{ id: 0, label: 'de' }] }" x-effect="console.log(languages)">
    @foreach (App\Models\Language::foreignLanguages() as $lang)
        <div class="flex items-center">
            <input
                value="{id: {{ $lang->language_id }}, label: '{{ $lang->language_code }}'}"
                x-model="languages" id="language"
                name="language" type="checkbox">
            <label for="language">{{ $lang->language_name }}</label>
        </div>
    @endforeach

    <template x-for="lang in languages">
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" x-bind:placeholder="lang.label">

        @error('title')
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        @enderror
    </template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use complex JS objects as values for input elements, they will be treated as strings. You should just store the ID of the selected languages in an array. Furthermore you should also create as many text inputs as languages you have, each with a unique name attribute e.g. `title_1`. You can hide the inputs belonging to unselected languages using `x-show` directive.

```
<div x-data="{ languages: [0] }" x-effect="console.log(languages)">
    @foreach (App\Models\Language::foreignLanguages() as $lang)
        <div class="flex items-center">
            <input
                value="{{ $lang->language_id }}"
                x-model="languages" id="language"
                name="language" type="checkbox">
            <label for="language">{{ $lang->language_name }}</label>
        </div>
    @endforeach

    @foreach (App\Models\Language::foreignLanguages() as $lang)
    <div x-show="languages.includes('{{ $lang->language_id }}')">    
        <input type="text" 
               name="title_{{ $lang->language_id }}" 
               id="title_{{ $lang->language_id }}" 
               x-bind:placeholder="{{ $lang->language_name }}">
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```